# window.onload function called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a simple form with post method. I am not sure why window.onload() function gets called twice below it shows up the page? Below is the code

```
  function window.onload() {        

       initialisePage();       

    }  
    <form id="frmMain" method="post" runat="Server"> 

</form>
```

I tried using document.isready function before calling initialisePage didn't help.

Comment: I don't see how it could be called at all given that if it is JS you have a syntax error in the declaration. Is there server-side stuff going on there too? Are you sure you've used the right tags on your question?

Comment: what is the <form> post's relation with the onload function?

Comment: The javascript code sits within script tag "<script language="Javascript"> . it is with an aspx file. The problem is not why it is not called but it gets called twice? So there isn't any syntax issue in the code.

Answer (score 5):

If window.onload gets called twice, means some changes are still happening on front side after initial load. 
A better to way would be by checking

```
window.onload = function() {
if(document.readyState == 'complete') {
myFunction();
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**SYNTAX ERROR** in your code. `onload` should be written as follow:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    initialisePage();       
}
</scipt>
```

**OR**

```
window.onload = initialisePage; // Thanks to @nnnnnn
```

[**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: And it should be inside a <script> tag

Comment: Or `window.onload = initialisePage;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload = initialisePage;
</scipt>
```

Comment: Consider editing your answer to include an explanation, showing *why/how* your code provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line of code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    initialisePage();
})
```

Comment: keep in mind $(document).ready is for before elements have rendered. and $(window).load is for after elements have rendered

Answer (score 0):

From the early 2000's I avoided using these types of hooks as they were undependable in these early days. Instead, I have always leaned on the tried and trued method of dropping in the 'init' call at the bottom of the page. It has never let me down.

```
    ...
    <script>
      body_loaded()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know there are edge cases where this would not be ideal but it works 99.9% of usecases and follows 'KISS' principles.